# How to make netbeans find my class path library

Tags: java, gradle, netbeans

I have netbeans 12.4 and java 11 installed on fedora. I have created a Gradle multi project. It compiles fine but code completion isn't working

In Netbeans, have created I library named Facebook in tools>libraries. I then extracted classes.jar from Gradle cache file .aar packages. I renamed and added these to Facebook Library class path

I can't seem to be able to find the class path in my java files when I do

```
    import com.facebook.*;
```

Netbeans says unable to find class path com.facebook.*;
What am I doing. wrong how can I make netbeans recognize my jar when I am coding like code completion

> Project build.gradle

```
description = 'Example Project'

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.0")
    }
}

allprojects {

    group = 'com.example'

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

> Project settings.gradle

```
rootProject.name = 'example'

include ':app'
```

> Module build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

description = 'app'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId("com.example.app")
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                arguments = ["room.schemaLocation":"$projectDir/schemas".toString()]
            }
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
        }
        
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    annotationProcessor 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core:1.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment:1.3.6'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.5'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.5'
    implementation 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:5.15.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    testImplementation 'androidx.room:room-testing:2.3.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
}
```

Comment: Tell me how to improve my question please

Comment: Can you provide step-by-step details on how you created and configured your project? Ideally, we need enough details to allow us to re-create the same problem you are facing.

Answer (score 0):

In the Projects window right-click on the name of the project that lacks library -> Properties ->

The Project Properties POP UP. In Categories tree select "Libraries" node ->

On the right side of the Project Properties window press "Add JAR/Folder" ->

And here Select jars you need.

You also can see my short Video How-To.

Comment: It's a Gradle project it doesn't have the library node you are speaking of